# Proving the following proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

I am asked to prove the following proposition but, due to omissions or just plain ignorance I've been unable to arrive at the correct answer. Your input will be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively we can reason that no object $a$ can satisfy $p$ because if it did we'd also have that something is $q$ (by first premiss), which is ruled out (by the second premiss). So, turning that idea into a natural deduction proof:

> Start a subproof with $p(a)$.
>
> Then it follows $\exists x p(x)$, and hence by the first premiss
> $\exists y q(y)$.
>
> But $\exists y q(y)$ and the second premiss lead to contradiction.
>
> Since $p(a)$ leads to contradiction we can apply reductio, drop the
> supposition, and conclude $\neg p(a)$.
>
> Universal quantifier introduction gives the target result.

How that goes in detail will depend on the system you are working with.

Comment: "But ∃yq(y) and the second premiss lead to contradiction." I don't see how this step is needed, nor useful.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Given we've started with p(a) as a temporary supposition, how else do you show that it leads to a contradiction?

Comment: I think I was confusing ∃xp(x) with ∃xq(x) before.  Now I see how the  ∃yq(y)  step is needed and useful.